# Is there any hook available in woocommerce to add additional line items in admin order details section

Tags: woocommerce, admin

I am saving some extra products to order meta during checkout and I want to show those products into woocommerce admin order details section and it need to look like regular products.

[image]

I am looking for any woocommerce hooks available to acheive this task without customization woocommerce core file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand but is this what you mean?:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'custom_info_after_order_itemmeta', 20, 3 );
function custom_info_after_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    //echo stuff here
}
```